# Can't figure out how to check my list and input with each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.8

I'm trying to make a simple wake up file in Python 3, but I can't seem to get my list and input to work with each other.

Here's the code:

```
from random import *

difficulty = (int(input("How many random numbers: ")))
list = []

for i in range(difficulty):
    numbers = randint(0, 10)
    list.append(numbers)
print(list)

answer = (input("Write the same numbers in the right order: "))

split = answer.split()
print(split)

if split == list:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong!")
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain what happens and what should happen.

Comment: please provide the two inputs and explain

Comment: Please add an example of input and output, i.e. what is the code expected to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a list of strigns to a list of ints, use:

```py
split = [int(a) for a in answer.split()]
```

Comment: Thank you @DownloadPizza now it's working!

Comment: Great, can you mark my answer as accepted so the question counts as answered?